# How can we give permission to profile user's to delete the notes and attachments?

Tags: profile, permissions, attachment, user, notes

I am stuck in a scenario in which I want to give access to the profile user's to delete the note and attachment. As I know, To delete a note or attachment, you must be the owner of the note or attachment or an administrator with the “Modify all Data” permission.
But I want to give permission to user other than the owner. How can I do it?

Answer (score 1):

1. Attachments will follow the same security as the parent record.
2. A profile user's will able to delete attachments if they have attachment parent object delete access.
3. Also profile user's must have read/write record level access of the parent object.

Comment: User couldn't delete the file others uploaded to his records, where he has permission to delete the parent record. But he can delete the files he uploaded.